# Get names of the available members of a Java class

Tags: java, member, names, field-names

I'm trying to get the member names of a class in Java. For instance, let's say I have the class:

```
class Dog
{
    private int legs = 4;
    private int ears = 2;
}
```

Is there anyway I can get a list of field names along with their types, such as

`{ "legs" : "int", "ears" : "int" }`.

*Note I wrote the example result in JSON for convenience, but I'm doing it in Java.*

Comment: what you are asking for is called [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Class#getDeclaredFields()`: -

```
for(Field f : Dog.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    f.setAccessible(true);
    String name = f.getName();
}
```

Comment: he should rather use `Class#getDeclaredFields()`

Answer (score 3):

```
Field[] fields = Dog.class.getFields();
```

and call `getName()` for each element